# Match group assignments between columns

Tags: r

I am trying to check the accuracy rate of a clustering algorithm, with a dataframe that looks like the one here. The `orig.gp` refers to the original grouping, which is the "correct" group assignment. The `new.gp` refers to the grouping assigned by the clustering algorithm.

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:9,
                 orig.gp = c(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
                 new.gp = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1) )
df

#   id orig.gp new.gp
# 1  1       1      2
# 2  2       1      2
# 3  3       1      3
# 4  4       2      3
# 5  5       2      3
# 6  6       2      1
# 7  7       3      1
# 8  8       3      1
# 9  9       3      1
```

What I am trying to determine is whether the same ids are assigned the same grouping as the `orig.gp`. The group number itself is not that important, as the number is arbitrary. Ideally, I would like to achieve something like this:

```
#   orig.gp new.gp  correct
# 1       1      2      yes
# 2       1      2      yes
# 3       1      3       no
# 4       2      3      yes
# 5       2      3      yes
# 6       2      1       no
# 7       3      1      yes
# 8       3      1      yes
# 9       3      1      yes
```

To illustrate, in the original grouping, group 1 consists of ids 1, 2, 3; group 2 consists of ids 4, 5, 6; group 3 consists of 7, 8, 9. In the new grouping, ids 1, 2 are correctly assigned into the same group, thus the "yes" in the correct column. I would like to determine whether the same ids are assigned into the same groups as the original groupings.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you perhaps add a bit more of an explanation as to how you arrive at your desire result?

Comment: How would you break ties? For example, if values of `new.gp` were evenly split across two different values of `orig.gp`, how would you determine whether classification was correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand your problem, it is basically one of recoding. Namely, you want to identify observations that fall on the diagonal of a crosstabulation of `new.gp` and `orig.gp`, but the values of `new.gp` are mislabeled.

What I propose here is basically recoding the values of `new.gp` based on a simple crosstabulation (see `tab` below). The recoding is done by taking the modal value of `orig.gp` for each possible value of `new.gp` and assuming that this mode is the correct value label. I then use `recode` from **car** to perform the recoding.

```
library("car")
tab <- with(df, table(new.gp, orig.gp))
tab
##       orig.gp
## new.gp 1 2 3
##      1 0 1 3
##      2 2 0 0
##      3 1 2 0
df$recoded <- recode(df$new.gp, paste(rownames(tab),colnames(tab)[max.col(tab)],sep='=',collapse=';'))
df$correct <- ifelse(df$orig.gp == df$recoded, "yes", "no")
```

The result:

```
> df
  orig.gp new.gp recoded correct
1       1      2       1     yes
2       1      2       1     yes
3       1      3       2      no
4       2      3       2     yes
5       2      3       2     yes
6       2      1       3      no
7       3      1       3     yes
8       3      1       3     yes
9       3      1       3     yes
```

Comment: That seems more like what they need

Comment: @RichardScriven I think so, but hard to say. I actually don't think this will work in all scenarios but it at least works on the example data.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I tried other recoding methods but wasn't able to achieve this. Thank you! @Thomas, can you clarify what you mean by not working in all scenarios? I am trying to learn more.